# Move application toolbar to gnome desktop toolbar, like OS X

Tags: gnome, xubuntu

I just installed Xubuntu, which came with Gnome. Is it possible to move the application toolbar to the top of the Desktop, mimicking the behavior of Mac OS X?

I'm talking about the toolbar "File Edit View History Bookmarks Tools Help" that appears in Firefox, for example. I would like to move this toolbar to the top of the desktop, making it part of the "Applications Places FF Help".

Comment: I recall there being a plugin, but it wasn't exactly stable. It's been a while though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [globalmenu](http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/).